# Excel VBA Soap Header

Tags: xml, vba, excel, soap

I am working on connecting to a web service in Excel-VBA, but my code is not connecting.

I know that the header information from the `SoapUI` file, that I was previously using, did work.

Here is what `SoapUI` sends:

```
POST https://api.e-value.net/PeopleGroup_1_0.cfc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction:""
Content-Length: 577
Host: api.e-value.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

What code would I use to include that information in the header before I use the send command?

Comment: Please provide the code you already tried to use.

Answer (score 0):

One uses setRequestHeader I think.  So something like this...

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim oXHR As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set oXHR = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    oXHR.Open "POST", "https://api.e-value.net/PeopleGroup_1_0.cfc"
    oXHR.setRequestHeader "HTTP/1.1 Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"
    '....


End Sub
```